# How to add values to multiple ranges?

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to make a piece of code that puts input ranges into predefined ranges. It checks `start` and `end` and then increments the `range` variable with the corresponding instance number. The code below increments first two `range.number` variables but it should also increment the third one because `input1`'s end is less than `range3`'s end. How can I make this work?

```
class Range:
    def __init__(self, start, end, number):
        self.start = start
        self.end = end
        self.number = number
    def __str__(self):
        return "%s, %s, %s" % (self.start, self.end, self.number)
class Input:
    def __init__(self, start, end):
        self.start = start
        self.end = end
    def __str__(self):
        return "%s, %s" % (self.start, self.end)

range1 = Range(1,5,0)
range2 = Range(5,8,0)
range3 = Range(8, 15, 0)

rangesArray = []
rangesArray.append(range1)
rangesArray.append(range2)
rangesArray.append(range3)

input1 = Input(2, 14)

# print(range1)
# print(input1)


# print(rangesArray[0], rangesArray[1])
for i in range(len(rangesArray)):
    if input1.start >= rangesArray[i].start:
        rangesArray[i].number += 1
        if input1.end > rangesArray[i].end:
            rangesArray[i+1].number += 1
print(rangesArray[0].number, rangesArray[1].number, rangesArray[2].number)'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution by @Aviad Levy would work fine for your problem.
But I would like to add a little modification to it.

 The code will throw `IndexError: list index out of range` if your input satisfies the second condition at last iteration. Because there are no more element left in the list to increase the number.
The below code will help to solve that problem.

```
for i in range(len(rangesArray)):
    if input1.start >= rangesArray[i].start: 
        rangesArray[i].number += 1
    if input1.end > rangesArray[i].end and i!= len(rangesArray)-1: #condition to ensure that list index doesn't go out of range
        rangesArray[i+1].number += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `input1.start` is less that any `rangesArray[i]` for `i >= 2`, so you only entered the if on the first iteration.
You can solve it if you'll set the second condition outside the first condition:

```
for i in range(len(rangesArray)):
    if input1.start >= rangesArray[i].start:
        rangesArray[i].number += 1
    if input1.end > rangesArray[i].end:
        rangesArray[i+1].number += 1
print(rangesArray[0].number, rangesArray[1].number, rangesArray[2].number)
```